# How should array be formatted for fputcsv result to be horizontal not vertical?

Tags: php, arrays, fopen, fputcsv

My `$array` looks like this in source code of my browser;

```
Array(
  [0] => 2015-01-15
  [1] => 2015-02-15
  [2] => 2015-03-15
)
```

My code to export this to a csv file is;

```
$fp = fopen("file.csv", "w");
fputcsv($fp, $array)
fclose($fp);
```

The output of the csv is horizontal. eg;

```
2015-01-01 | 2015-02-01 | 2015-03-01
```

I want it vertically;

```
2015-01-01
2015-02-01
2015-03-01
```

I don't know how to do this. I tried adding;

```
$fp = fopen("file.csv", "w", $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"');
```

And it didn't work. I tried creating a different array to test;

```
$array = array("2015-01-01", "2015-02-01", "2015-03-01");
```

And that gave the same horizontal result. I am open to changing the style/format of my array. Whatever gets the job done.

Comment: if you just want a single value per line, why bother with csv at all? `fprint()` would serve you better without the overhead of generating a single-value csv record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) writes a line. For multiple lines you need to make multiple calls.

If each element in the array goes on a new line, just iterate the array:

```
   $fp = fopen("file.csv", "w");
    foreach($array as $element)
        fputcsv($fp, array($element));
    fclose($fp);
```

Note (as per comment by Rizier123) that you need to make `$element` an array.

Comment: When I try that I get `Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given` for each "element"

Comment: @mike3875 Just use this line: `fputcsv($fp, [$element]);`

Comment: Thanks that works. What's it called when you do that with the `[ ]`s?

Comment: @mike3875 It's just an array so you make an array with one element. It's the same syntax as `array()` just a bit shorter

Comment: @mike3875 that is simply creating an array. `[]` and `array()` do the same thing - square bracket syntax is available from php5.4 onward